# What should we do about snarky comments denigrating specific works?

Tags: discussion, comments

There's a trend on SciFi.SE, where any mentions of works that are less popular with fans (Dune prequels, Highlander II, Matrix sequels, Star Wars prequels) are frequently met with snarky comments denigrading the unpopular works.

> "What Prequels"? (just commented on my own question today about Dune :)
>
> "Too bad that movie didn't have any sequels" (insert XKCD comic).

Usually the snark is **not** really offensive or rude (e.g. it almost never rises to the level where it should be flagged and deleted on that basis).

However, it's a noticeable and pervasive pattern, and there's a possibility that it can make users who like those works feel unwelcome.

What should we do with such type of comments as a policy? Leave them alone? Ban them?

*(again, the assumption is that none of the comments in question are really rude or offensive)*

Comment: Excellent question. And the examples you provided are the *really* "light" versions. There's worse.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm guilty of some of that snark. But it's acceptable on SciFi.SE culture, since the site tone in general is less formal.

Answer (score 20):

### Flag 'em.

It might be arguable whether they count as "rude or offensive", but at best they're "not constructive".

This falls under the same basic rules of courtesy as [this recently-featured main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289398/278659): just as you should be able to respect others' political viewpoints, you should also be able to respect their choice of literature. If you want to argue that *Pride and Prejudice* is a badly written novel because XYZ, that's fine. If you just want to scoff at *Pride and Prejudice* and make those who like it afraid to voice their opinions, that's *not* OK.

Comment: Or calling works "nonsense". ;-)

Comment: Am I gonna get banned from the site if I admit to having never read *Pride and Prejudice*?

Comment: @ChristianRau - "nonsense" would actually fall under "rude or offensive" in my book, without any caveats, and would be flagged as such on sight.

Comment: @DVK I started reading *Pride and Prejudice*, couldn't stand it, and gave up. I've only seen a film version. Feel free to shoot me.

Comment: @DVK Maybe donkeys are migratory animals?

Comment: +1 for the "at best the're not constructive". Flag and let the mods decide!

Comment: Mods will handle our flags *right away* (tm)

Comment: @DVK: you probably aren't going to be banned, because we don't ban people from Sci Fi SE just because they haven't read Harry Potter or haven't watched Star Wars.

Comment: @b_jonas - ***We should do***

Comment: @Valorum Some of us value quality over popularity ;-)