# How can I access a reply/comment on a deleted question?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug

I posted a comment on the question [What does claim to notoriety mean in this sentence?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8094), in which I suggested that there was no special meaning, the words meant what they normally mean, and therefore the question was pointless (although I put it more politely than that).

I later received a message in my inbox that someone [had replied to my comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8094/what-does-claim-to-notoriety-mean-in-this-sentence?noredirect=1#comment13980_8094):

> @Chappo I'm not sure what you mean by "the level we would expect".
>   We've taken...

However, I'm unable to access the full comment, as "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

**My question is: are higher-rep users and/or moderators able to view deleted questions (in which case, would someone with those privileges mind posting here what the full comment was and who it was from)?**

From the fragment available, it seems likely that the comment was providing a perspective (and possibly additional information) that might be useful for me as a relatively new LiteratureSE user (though I've been a visitor to other SE sites for over 6 years and a regular ELU contributor for 3 years). If my own comment was either off the mark or could have been better worded, I would welcome the feedback. It's frustrating to know that someone took the time to compose the reply and I can't benefit from it.

My supplementary question - more a rhetorical comment really - is: is it a SE design flaw to allow a fragment of a message to be delivered to a user's inbox when the full message cannot be viewed? If a comment has been deleted (whether on its own, or because it was connected to a question or answer that has been deleted), wouldn't it be better for the inbox message to be automatically deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a small scope discussion. Here's the context, posted because the comments weren't deleted, even if the OP was:

[image: small discussion - no transcription available]

Rand linked [How will we avoid literature snobbery?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-will-we-avoid-literature-snobbery) and [meaning](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). Christopher Strobbe also linked [meaning](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

This isn't a design flaw in SE per se, because there are users who can see these questions - over 10k reputation on graduated sites, and over 2k on beta sites like this one. You can also see certain notifications, particularly from moderators' comments, on certain deleted posts *you* own. Still, it's kind of annoying, I get that.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. The comments provide useful feedback. I'd intended "level" to refer to the difference between asking what the author intended (i.e. a "literary" level), compared to asking what an expression means in general English (i.e. a language comprehension level). By not being clear enough, I've invited Rand's (mis)interpretation of snobbery.

Comment: Glad to help, it sounds like you found it useful. :)